# How is binary data handled in json?

Tags: json

How can I put binary data in a json string?

The binary data can't be encoded in a base64 string or something like that. Basically I need to know how to put a raw byte array as-is inside a json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format natively doesn't support binary data. You have to encode it in some ways to convert binary data into text strings that can be accepted as a JSON string.

The most common way of doing so is [Base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

```json
{
    "this_is_base_64": "aGVsbG8hIHVuZGVydGhldm9pZCEgSGVyZSBjYW4gYmUgc29tZSBCaW5hcnkgRGF0YSE="
}
```

Or alternatively, you can store individual bytes as a number array if the data you're willing to encode is not terribly large.

```json
{
    "my_data": [127, 21, 62, 31, 0, 16, 71, 23, 44, 51, 14, 61, 41, 65]
}
```

Comment: You can *try* putting binary data between two double quotes in a JSON text. But I doubt it would be any useful since most parser won't be able to parse it.

Comment: Another common way of encoding it is as a hex string -- a string of (an even number of) hex digits.

Comment: @Miigon I'll accept the answer for the information of Json not supporting it natively, however I explicitly said I can't use base64. This data at hand is not ASCII. If i encode it using base64 I'll simply lose information in each byte.

Comment: @underthevoid It shouldn't have. Which base64 library/method are you using to encode the data? Some library might try to be smart and handle charset/CRLF for you, which ruins binary data. However base64 is perfectly capable of encoding and decoding binary data with the right setting for your base64 library (or method).

Comment: @underthevoid In fact, a lot of RESTful apis encodes files and images into base64 for transmission within http, then decodes it at the other end to get back the original file or image,

Comment: @Miigon Oh I didn't know about that. I thought base64 would actually compress a binary value in a lossy operation. So I can safely use base64 to encode every possible kind of binary data representation?

Comment: @underthevoid Yes. You can. That's one major use case of base64 :-) The format itself doesn't change anything about the original data. But beware how you encode it though. If you're using C/C++ and uses a encode method that takes only a `const char *`, but no length, as input, than that's most likely not gonna work. Since it likely assumed a zero-terminated string and not binary data. Your binary data can get chopped off in this case but still, it's not the fault of base64.